# PHP Performance: Storing a Class Object in a Session vs Static vs Globals

Tags: php, performance, session, web

I've been looking for an answer on this, so far I have been unable to find an answer. My question is; What is the best way to store a huge global class that does not require any dynamic input, it only needs to be used once.

Lets take for example a template class:

```
<?php
class Design_API{
   function loadfile($file){
     //load file here
   }

   // do file manipulation here

   function presentfile(){
      echo($this->file);
   }

}
?>
```

Utilizing this class as a basic example of a layout. What would be the best way performance and security wise to use it. Would it be to create an instance of it as a global; store the instance in a session; or simply make it a static class.

Also, say we used a session if 2 clients access the site at the same exact millisecond, would php lock the session file forcing client 2's web load to take longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit too mixed up to be answered in a consistent way, so here are some points:

- one client does not block another, unless they're accessing a shared resource
- sessions are not shared resources between different users, forget about this misconception
- wherever you store objects hardly makes a difference in performance
- it makes even less of a difference between different requests and users, since no resources are shared between requests
- code what you mean first and what is most maintainable, optimize this for performance later when it is proven to be slow (which it likely won't be)
- avoid globals wherever possible
- don't store stuff in the session that does not belong there, like code
- avoid `static` classes as much as possible, they cause code coupling, which should be reduced
- `static` classes are not necessarily faster

Comment: The concept regarding sessions wasn't necessarily that the sessions are shared. Because in truth they aren't I know that.

It's that by storing many sessions and the longer it takes for a session to be handles PHP leaves the session file on the server open to write. Which causes the server to lock if more than 2 clients are attempting to access the same php files with those sessions.

As described here; http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Comment: @Chris Each user gets his own session file, so it will only block *for the same user*, not across different users.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is to make the class a Singleton class and use the static method to instatiante it.

Storing the object in session will involve serialization and de-serialization which is very bad for performance. Also if you store any resources in the class they can't be serialized.

Comment: I'll severely disagree that *Singletons* are "the best way". They're *a* way with some drawbacks, namely: `static` calls == code coupling == reducing flexibility and testability.

Comment: While I agree with your comment regarding `Singleton` as a pattern, it's just one of the implementations of singleton as a concept (i.e. single instance only), and I think it's imperative to point out that the concept itself isn't necessarily bad. E.g., in most cases, it makes most sense to only have a single instance of database connection. There are quite a few other patterns that implement this concept, which don't have the disadvantages you mentioned.